# When should .mo files be generated?

Tags: python, application-development, translation

I am creating a python GTK3 program. I'll like to add translation support. I know how to create a .pot and .po file. However in order to make the application available in multiple languages, I need to generate .mo files. I read [here](http://prioritiseapp.wordpress.com/category/tutorials/) that the way to generate .mo files is using the **msgfmt.make** command.

My question is whether I (the developer) should generate the .mo files manually in my computer and then instruct the .deb installer to move the files into the usr/share/locale/en_GB/ folder when it is being installed? Or should the .deb installer generate these .mo files while the user installs my program on his system?

In way this could be summarized as "**are the .mo files machine dependant?**"

My folder structure is as follow

```
nstrain-0.1
   /debian
   /data
   /help
   /nstrain_lib
   nstrain.desktop
   nstrain.py
```

where nstrain.py is the main executable file which the .desktop file runs when the user clicks on my program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Binary [MO files](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/MO-Files.html) need to be generated at build time. This means that your build system needs to have a build target to read the textual [PO files](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/gettext/manual/html_node/PO-Files.html) used as the source and convert them to the binary MO files that will be installed in the user's system. As you correctly point out, the [`msgfmt`](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/gettext/manual/html_node/msgfmt-Invocation.html) command (part of the [gettext tools](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html)) will ultimately create them.

So to answer the last part of the question, yes, MO files are machine-dependant.

### Creating MO files the hard way

Now onto how to create them, in the standard gettext layout you'll generally have all PO files in the same directory, one per language and named after each language's ISO-639 2-letter or 3-letter code:

```
po/
po/ca.po
po/de.po
...
```

If you want to build them manually, you'll have to walk through each file in that dir and invoke `msgfmt` manually, e.g.

```
$ msgfmt -c po/ca.po -o build/locale/LC_MESSAGES/ca/myapp.mo
```

But you don't want to be doing this when there is already an established way and automated tools created especially for the operation of building MO files.

Furthermore, these tools take care of other associated tasks, such as extracting translations from the code and putting them all together in a POT file to give to translators to do their work.

### Creating MO files the clever way

If you are using Python, I very much recommeng using the [python-distutils-extra](https://launchpad.net/python-distutils-extra) package (install p-d-e), which automates and hides away the complexity by just having to specify the following in the `setup.py` file you'll use to build, install and distribute your app. Same example as @dobey was already pointing out on his answer:

```
DistUtilsExtra.auto.setup(
    name='myapp',
    version='0.1',
    #license='GPL-3',
    #author='Your Name',
    #author_email='email@ubuntu.com',
    #description='UI for managing …',
    #long_description='Here a longer description',
    #url='https://launchpad.net/myapp'
)
```

That will take care of everything for you.

If you want to test translations before shipping them, you can use the handy `build_i18n` command from python-distutils-extra:

```
$ python setup.py build_i18n
```

This will build all the PO files in your `/po` folder and will put them under `build` (it will create it if it doesn't exist) in the same layout gettext expects when they are installed in a system.

You can then test your application with translations either by:
 * Copying the contents of `/build` to `/usr/share/locale`, or
 * Pointing your app to the build directory using the [`gettext.bindtextdomain()`](http://docs.python.org/library/gettext.html#gettext.bindtextdomain) function:

```
gettext.bindtextdomain(domain='myapp', localedir='/home/me/dev/myapp/build')
```

### Being even cleverer

Stand on the shoulder of giants. Simply create a test application with [Quickly](http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/) and copy how translations are set up in `setup.py`, which basically boils down to using the `DistutilsExtra` module in `auto` mode, as outlined above.

You can use the test app to play with generating translations too and learn how the generation works.

### Packaging

The tarball you put together as part of a release should not include the .mo files. That is, you don't have to build them manually. That needs to happen when either someone builds the tarball contents to install manually or when e.g. a Debian binary package is being created.

Looking at your source tree, I would suggest again to use a build system such as python-distutils-extra, which will also help with the packaging. Roughly, you'll need to:

- Create a `setup.py` file with contents similar to those suggested above
- Create the packaging control files under debian/. Using p-d-e your `debian/rules` file can become very simple and consist of only a few lines.

Actually, you might just want to use Quickly to create the harness for the build and packaging system for your app and then replace Quickly's generated source code for the test application with your application's code.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. I actually did try using quickly when I first started this project, however quickly creates lots of files like builders.py, etc etc...that I do not understand the working. This is why I created everything from scratch by myself without any help from quickly..So I will try to use python-distutils-extra somehow in my project..

Comment: You're welcome :) Regarding files that Quickly create, most of them constitute only the harness of the application. For most Quickly apps, you can ignore what's under the `myapp_lib` folder and concentrate on just the `MyAppWindow.py` file. If you find that's still too complex, there is yet another alternative: create the basic structure of an app with Quickly, remove all source code files, remove the part above the comment line from the generated `setup.py` file and just drop your source code inside the myapp folder (assuming your project is called myapp). It's not supported, but doable.

Comment: The solution is quit outdated but looks great. Can you update your question using a modern pyproject.toml based Python project and without using 3rd party dependencies?

Answer (score 3):

Given you are using Python, I'll presume that you are using setuptools/distribute/distutils as the build system. In such a case, you can use DistUtilsExtra.auto instead:

```
from DistUtilsExtra.auto import setup

setup(
    name="Your Project",
    version="0.1",
    ...
)
```

You can pass the same arguments to setup() as you normally do for your package. DistUtilsExtra.auto can automatically handle many system integration pieces such as translations, including translating static text files such as .desktop files.

Comment: I do not use setuptools/distribute/distutils for my project. My project has basically .py, .pyc and .ui files. I then use debian packaging to ensure that files are installed in the correct directory..and my desktop file basically executes the main .py file.

Comment: You should switch to using setup.py for it then. Using a proper build system takes care of a lot of work that otherwise has to be done manually, and makes supporting many system configurations much easier, and automatic.

Comment: yeah I realise that now..I will ask another question soon about disutils. I get the concept of using setup.py..but I am missing the bigger picture. I mean why use setup.py when I have already packaged it in .deb format? But do not answer this question since I will create a new askubuntu question for this :)